# Shared folder between host and our guest in VirtualBox

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware

How can I configure the guest OS (your Linux distribution in specific) so as to have a shared folder between host and guest. From Win 10 I created a shared folder and made it shared to all, and from Linux I run the command:

/usr/sbin/usermod -aG vboxsf oracle

However, I cannot yet pass through any files!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to install the [Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) let let virtualbox set up a share for you. check out the virtualbox manual at
[3.12. Shared folders](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idm1699) and  [4.3. Shared folders](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders)

Comment: Your Welcome @general46